# storing output values of five loops in an array by matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, loops, store

There is one equation has 5 variable parameters. Each parameter has one for loop so this equation depends on the 5 for loops and i want to appear the results of this equation in matrix array. How can i do it?

```
    for m1= 1:m1_end;
    m1_vec=zeros(1,col_no/m1_end)+m1;
    input_mat(1,col_no/m1_end*(m1-1)+1:col_no/m1_end*m1)= m1_vec;


    for m2= 1:m2_end;
        m2_vec=zeros(1,col_no/m2_end^2)+m2;
         input_mat(2,col_no/m2_end^2*(m2-1)+1:col_no/m2_end^2*m2)= m2_vec;

        for k1=1:k1_end;
            k1_vec=zeros(1,col_no/k1_end^3)+k1;
             input_mat(3,col_no/k1_end^3*(k1-1)+1:col_no/k1_end^3*k1)= k1_vec;

            for k2=1:k2_end;
                   k2_vec=zeros(1,col_no/k2_end^4)+k2;
                    input_mat(4,col_no/k2_end^4*(k2-1)+1:col_no/k2_end^4*k2)= k2_vec;

                for k3=1:k3_end; 
                     input_mat(5,col_no/k3_end^5*(k3-1)+1:col_no/k3_end^5*k3)= k3;
      M=[m1 0 ; 0 m2 ];
    K=[k1+k2 -k2 ; -k2 k2+k3];
  eigen_values=sqrt(eig(inv(M)*K))

                end

            end
        end
    end
    end
```

How to show the all results of eigen_values in matrix ?

Comment: It is very unclear what you want to achieve. Probably most of the code isn't needed. Could you provide an example of the output you would like?

Comment: Or, can you write a mathematical formula?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is a bit messy, but you could start with something to hold all eigen_values

Either a matrix (if it is just a scalar) or a cell array if it is a vector.

Then each time after calculating eigen_values assign it to the correct place in your storage variable.

For example, if it is a scalar, and you track your progress with `t`:

```
all_eigen_values(t) = eigen_values;
```